# Access Violation Reading Location C Array

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
int calculate_sum_dice(int *dice[2]) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    sum += *dice[i];
}
return (sum);
}
```

dice is an integer array initialized as follows:

```
int die1 = roll_die();
int die2 = roll_die();
int *dice[2] = { die1, die2 };
```

the line

```
sum += *dice[i]
```

throws an Access Violation Reading Location error

I tried to do

```
sum += dice[i]
```

but it throws an error as well.

I am new to C so i appreciate any help despite how trite it might seem.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an array of 2 pointers and an array of 2 values?

Comment: You are declaring `dice` as an array of two pointers to `int`, but you are initializing it and using it as if it were an array of `int`.

Comment: why not `int dice[] = { die1, die2 };`

Comment: `int *dice[2] = { die1, die2 };` type mismatch here.

Comment: So 
int *dice[2];
Is declaring dice as an array of pointers not of ints?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you this worked

Comment: And your compiler emitted no warnings?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 says `warning C4047: 'initializing': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` when forcing it to compile as C at warning level 4. C++ is an error as expected.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.  Don't post code here that has warnings, since they will often point directly at your problem.  Learn the difference between an integer and a pointer to an integer.  A good C tutorial would probably be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a constraint violation:

```
int *dice[2] = { die1, die2 };
```

Meaning it is not valid C code. Your compiler must produce a diagnostic message pointing at that line, or it is not a proper C compiler. If it did, then don't ignore the message. If it didn't, get a better compiler.

As for getting the code to work, simply drop the pointer declaration in the caller and function both.

```
int dice[2] = { die1, die2 };
calculate_sum_dice(dice);


int calculate_sum_dice(int dice[2])
{
  ...
  sum += dice[i];
```

`dice` in the function will silently "decay" to a pointer to the first element of the array.